# In bash, how do I get possible completions to disappear afterwards?

Tags: bash, zsh, command-line-interface

In bash, when I hit tab and the completion is ambiguous, it appears like this on my screen:

```
chris@host / $ cd fo
foo/ for/ foz/
chris@host / $ cd fo
```

I then continue typing, but I get to another completion:

```
chris@host / $ cd fo
foo/ for/ foz/
chris@host / $ cd foo/ba
bar/ bat/
chris@host / $ cd foo/ba
```

And another:

```
chris@host / $ cd fo
foo/ for/ foz/
chris@host / $ cd foo/ba
bar/ bat/
chris@host / $ cd foo/bar/ba
bad/ bay/ baz
chris@host / $ cd foo/bar/baz
chris@host /foo/bar/baz $
```

I'm left with a bunch of completion suggestions in my terminal history, which to me is clutter that I don't want. In zsh this does not happen -- once you're finished with a suggestion, it disappears from the terminal, and all you see is:

```
chris@host / $ cd foo/bar/baz
chris@host /foo/bar/baz $
```

Is there any way to get bash to act similarly or is this a zsh-only thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware that's just how `bash` works.
If you prefer the `zsh` behavior, use `zsh`.

(The wonderful thing about standard shells is there are so many to choose from!)